# All curves homologous to zero implies space is simply connected?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis, algebraic-topology

The title says it all. Is it true that if $X$ is a topological space on which all loops are homologous to zero then $X$ is simply connected, ie all loops are homotopic to zero?

I know that the result is true if $X$ is a domain in $\mathbb{C}$, but I wonder if it also holds for arbitrary topological spaces.

Also, please notice that I am aware that, in general, a loop can be homologous to zero without being homotopic to zero. Here I am asking what happens in the case when **all** loops are homologous to zero.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Not when the fundamental group is a [perfect group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perfect_group), because the first homology group is equal to zero if and only if the fundamental group is equal to its commutator.

Comment: And I guess we have constructions to make reasonable spaces with whatever (reasonable) fundamental groups we want?

Comment: It seems that every group can in fact be realized as the fundamental group of a 2-dim CW complex. See http://home.iitk.ac.in/~gabhi/MTH648Presentation.pdf

Comment: The Poincare Homology Sphere is a classic example.